# Meaning of や in 「もうどうだっていいや」

Tags: particles, sentence-final-particles

What's the appropriate definition for や in this lyric? Can anyone give similar examples of や? jisho.org has this definition (#4) "interjection expressing surprise" but that doesn't seem right.

> 僕達このまんまでいいんですか
>
> おいどうすんだよ
>
> もうどうだっていいや

This is from the song ロストワンの号哭 (the lost one's weeping)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [デジタル大辞泉](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/220994/meaning/m0u/%E3%82%84/) and [大辞林](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%82%84-647430#E5.A4.A7.E8.BE.9E.E6.9E.97.20.E7.AC.AC.E4.B8.89.E7.89.88), this や is a 終助詞 (sentence ending particle) rather than a 感動詞 (interjection).

> 「 3⃣-2 軽く言い放すような気持ちを表す。『もう、どうでもいい**や**』」(デジタル大辞泉)
>
> 「四-② 軽く言い放つような気持ち，または，なげやりな気持ちを表す。『まあ，いい**や**』『今さらどうしようもない**や**』」(大辞林)

---

I think や as an "interjection expressing surprise" is something like... 「（ 感 ）
① 驚いた時に発する語。『**や**、こんな所にあった』」(大辞林) / 「〘感〙驚きの気持ちを表す。やっ。やあ。『**や**、こいつは有り難い』『**や**、あいつはだれだ』」(明鏡国語辞典)

Comment: Just in case someone has difficulty reading those definitions, 「や」  is a sentence-ender for light and casual kind of declaration.

Comment: @l'électeur ありがとうございます。至らなくてすみません。

Comment: 「軽く言い放つ」のほうは翻訳により何かが失われそうな定義ですね。どこだったかで見た「軽い諦めの気持ち」というのが個人的には好きです。