# What does だっていい mean?

Tags: sentence, reading-comprehension

[image]

" 先だって " appears to be a proper word but I don't see how it fits here?

"Which one... doesn't matter"?

Comment: Related [Meaning of や in 「もうどうだっていいや」](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/34224)

Answer (score 2):

先だって can be interpreted in several ways:

1. **先だって【せんだって】** (先達て in kanji): "recently; a while ago" ([a lexicalized adverb](https://jisho.org/word/%E5%85%88%E3%81%A0%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6))

   > 先だってお送りした書類の件ですが、…
   > Regarding the document we sent you earlier, ...
2. **先立って【さきだって】** ≈ 先行して: te-form of [先立つ【さきだつ】](https://jisho.org/word/%E5%85%88%E7%AB%8B%E3%81%A4), "to go ahead; to precede"

   > 一般販売に先立ってテスト販売を行う。
   > Test sales will be conducted prior to general sales.
3. **先【さき】だって**: 先 ("earlier; first") + だ (copula) + って (quotative)

   > Sチケットを持っている人の方が先だって言ってた。
   > He said the S-ticket holders were first.
4. **interrogative + 先【さき】だって**: 先 ("earlier; first") + [だって](https://jisho.org/word/%E3%81%A0%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6) ("even", "-ever")

In your case, it's 4. This だって is a particle used in the same way as だって as in 誰だって (whoever), どれだって ("whichever"), いつだって ("whenever"), etc. It's more emphatic and colloquial than 誰でも, etc. See [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/50294/5010).

> どっちが先だっていーよ、もう。
> ≈ どちらが先でもいいよ、もう。
> Come on, whoever {comes earlier / goes ahead / does it first}, I'm fine.
> Hey, I don't mind whichever is first!

Note that 1 is a fairly formal adverb used in business exchanges, and it never appears in informal conversation.

Answer (score 1):

(Edited upon chocolate's comment)

It's not 先{せん}だって (*the other day*), but 先{さき} is used on its own.

For example,

- 私が先だ

means *I'm the first* (though, strictly speaking, it doesn't have to be *first*. it just means the speaker does it earlier than the listener).

どっちが先だっていい <strike>is a colloquial version of</strike> can be understood as どっちが先であって(も)いい, meaning *whichever is the first (does not matter)*.  So the speaker is saying the order (understood from the context) does not matter.

Another <strike>contraction</strike> alternative is どっちが先でもいい.

---

Grammatically [って](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6/#jn-147762) is an independent particle according to 大辞泉. I would say this is the usage of 2-1.

> １ ある事柄を話題として取り上げて示す意を表す。…は。…というのは。「あなた―親切な人ね」「彼―だれのこと」

In other words, it is a topic marker: *As regards which is the first, it does not matter*.

Comment: `どっちが先だっていい is a colloquial version of どっちが先であって(も)いい` と言ってしまうと、 「だって」が「であって」の音変化であると言っているように聞こえてしまわないでしょうか。副助詞「だって」は、助動詞「だ」＋副助詞「とて」から来ていますし、「って」はもともと「とて」で、格助詞「と」＋接続助詞「て」から来ていますよね。

Comment: @chocolate 大辞泉だと「２の語源については、係助詞「とて」の促音添加、「という」「というのは」の音変化などとして扱うこともある」と少し留保がついてますね。自分は（「とて」の１ではなく）こちらをとりました。

Answer (score 1):

Since あって attaches to the -te form of adjectives and verbs as well, with elision of the preceding vowel,

どっちが先で+あって→どっちが先だって=どっちが先でも

誰が来て+あって→誰が来たって=誰が来ても

どれが欲しくて+あって→どれが欲しくたって=どれが欲しくても

it might be better to think of this あって as a (special) use of the -te form of有る.

Comment: でも明鏡国語辞典には、副助詞「だって」は、助動詞「だ」＋副助詞「とて」でできてるって書いてありますけど？「って」はもともと「とて」で、格助詞「と」＋接続助詞「て」から来ていますし。デジタル大辞泉にも「だって」は助動詞「だ」＋係助詞「とて」、広辞苑にも「ダトテ」から、って書いてあります

Comment: では、「誰が来たって」と「どれがほしくたって」との構造をどう解析しますか。

Comment: ん？？わからないから聞いてるんですか？それとも辞書に載っているのは間違いだってことでしょうか？

Comment: 「だ」+「とて」→「だって」という語形変化を知っていますが、辞書から引用したのは「来たって」、「ほしくたって」というような構造には言及しないので、それを知るべく聞いているだけです。